# Do I Need to Use the Registered Symbol?

Tags: trademark

I am writing a science paper for school and I am including the name of a product. Do I need to include the registration symbol after the name of the product?

"The monitor that was used in this experiment was the Garmin Vivoactive (®?)."

Comment: I sorta, kinda understand what you’re asking but you need to give us more information. What is “a product”? What is “the registered symbol”? What is the purpose of the “scientific paper” - is it a school report or is it going to published in the international journal Nature?

Comment: @DaleM I am writing a school report and it goes something like, "The monitor that was used in this experiment was the Garmin Vivoactive (®?)."

Comment: Cool - edit that into your question

Comment: [This other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/is-it-ever-legally-beneficial-for-a-third-party-to-use-symbols-indicating-intell) has a great answer on why you *should* use them, despite them not being required.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not legally have to add the symbol. 
https://www.nutter.com/ip-law-bulletin/proper-use-of-trademarks-and-trademark-symbols##targetText=Use%20of%20trademark%20symbols%20is,phrase%2C%20and%2For%20logo.

It is just a way to show that something is a registered trademark.